# PHP Soap request from java

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a Java client and soap(php) on my website.
I would like to do something like this

(WARNING: PSEUDOCODE)

> Client: send message to soap page for example "ID=1"
>
> Soap: retrieve the "ID=1" part from request and *find the string linked with the ID(I don't need help here)*
>
> Client: retrieve string, output it.

Now, how would I

request(client)/retrieve(soap)/retrieve(client)?

I followed a youtube tutorial for setting up Soap, and I don't use wsdl
(Though if I understand this correctly this is one of the most important parts if I want to use Soap in the way that I intend to).

**And PLEASE, before downvoting, tell me why you are downvoting (if it is because no code is given, I would post code, but I have no idea even where to start -- this is because I tried to jump on the subject without knowing much, I know php though obviously).**

**Thanks.**

Comment: What's the problem? Creating a php [`SoapServer`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php) or creating the java client?

Comment: @Edwardth I have no Idea on how to handle this `request(client)/retrieve(soap)/retrieve(client)`, and I think wsdl files could help me with this, unfortunately though, I find myself in a middle point where some tutorials/docs are too complex or too simple.

Comment: watch a few hours worth of youtube videos on SOAP tutorials, then try it yourself, and if you get stuck at some point post that specific question, because right now you are basically asking "how do i do SOAP" which would take a book to answer. :)

Comment: @ClayFerguson well then could you at least link some youtube videos? Possibly something that doesn't have a strong indian accent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about php [SoapServer](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php), but it seems like you can just create one without a wsdl-file.
See: [PHP: minimal example of SOAP Server and Client](https://gist.github.com/elvisciotti/4586286).

After you have your php soap Server, i would try to create a wsdl-file, because it's easier to generate your java-classes from a wsdl-file.
Here is a [php-wsdl-creator](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-wsdl-creator/).

Now you can generate your java-classes with [`wsgen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html).
A tutorial for that: [JAX-WS : wsgen tool example](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsgen-tool-example/)